# Any open source message queue that can be used to send messages from COBOL to Java?

Tags: java, queue, messaging, cobol, mainframe

I have a Java stack (Tomcat, etc) and I need to send messages from a mainframe running COBOL to the Java end. Any of the open source queues available can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, [Java Messaging](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/) interoperates with IBM.  On the IBM side you need to be able to talk to MQSeries. Try starting with this [DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/businessintegration/wmq.html) site.

Answer (score 3):

[Websphere MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/) is going to be the best (i.e. most supported) method for doing this. There are clients for a large number of different systems and it runs on all the mainframe OS'. It's not open source but the client libraries can still be obtained for no money, I believe.